# Program Of forking processes using switch statement in C

Tags: c, switch-statement, fork

I'm trying to fork 2 processes from parent as following, but sometimes I get error(program don't finish) and I don't know why:

```
pid_t pidA, pidB;
pidA = fork();
switch (pidA) {
    case -1: 
        // error handling
        return -1;
    case 0:
        // first child code
        break;
    default: {
        // parent code 1
        pidB = fork();
        switch(pidB) {
            case -1:
                // error handling
                return -1;
            case 0:
                // second child code
                break;
            default:
                // parent code 2, I think it's the same like parent code 1. Am I right?
                waitpid(-1, NULL, 0);
                printf("parent\n");
                break;
         }
         // parent code 3, again same like parent code 1 and 2 ???
         // when I use printf("Parent\n"); here it prints Parent 2 times and I don't know why.
     }
 }
```

Can someone help me with this, find what is wrong here.
Some explanation would be great.
Thank you

Comment: You have two children; you wait for one of them to finish, but not for the other.  I'm not convinced by the use of `switch`.  I guess it can be made to work, but it looks like spaghetti in a way that properly crafted code using `if/then/else` does not…though clearly I'm biassed).

Answer (score 1):

Consider the process tree:

```
    P
   / \
  P   C1
 / \
P  C2
```

**First fork**: Splits into P and C1

**Second fork**: Splits into P and C2

`C1` returns and does not print anything.

`C2` breaks from switch, prints `Parent` (note capital p) and returns.

P prints `parent` and `Parent`.

So this explains why it prints `Parent` two times.

---

And as for the program not finishing, check the return value of [waitpid()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/waitpid) and try to debug it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you trying to do here? 
When you fork for the first time, your first child process will essentially do nothing. 
The parent will resume and fork again returning `pidB` and will then resume executing up until the `waitpid()` function is executed.

I assume you're trying to wait for the new child code to execute and then terminate before the parent continues to print "parent".

You're waiting on a PID of -1, which probably should be `pidB`.

If you put a `printf()` outside the switch block, the child will print "parent" on its way out, same with the parent that spawned it. You probably want a return statement instead of a break if you want the child to terminate immediately.

Running your code as-is, with the `printf` statement outside the second `switch` statement, this is my output, using `pidB` to show which process is printing:

```
parent
Parent: pid=25046
Parent: pid=0
```

The results show that the child is one of the ones printing as well.

If you add a return instead of a break in the inner switch case 0, this is what you get:

```
parent
Parent: pid=25095
```

Here is what I suggest

```
// parent code 1
    pidB = fork();
    switch(pidB) {
        case -1:
            // error handling
            return -1;
        case 0:
             // second child code
             break;
        default:
            // parent code 2, I think it's the same like parent code 1. Am I right?
            waitpid(pidB, NULL, 0); // wait for the child process to finish by using the PID of the child as the argument to waitpid
            printf("parent\n");
            break;
     }
     // the child will execute anything here unless you return or otherwise prevent the child process from getting here.
```

Comment: I'm trying to fork 2 processes form parent. Each process will then run it's own code, this is just example, sample. And I want parent to wait for his children and then run his own code.

Comment: I've updated my answer to reflect what you should be doing with respect to the child and parent. Remember, when you fork(), each process executes in parallel, on its own. If there's specific pieces of code that you don't want executed, then you need to make sure it's in an area that the "parent" would never otherwise get to, and vice-versa. Make sure to use the return values of waitpid() to understand what's going on.

Comment: waitpid(pidB, NULL, 0); waits only for second child, what about the first one? I want to wait for each process that parent created and then run parent code. I changed break to return, but it didn't help 50 times program finishes correct 51 time it fails. Maybe if I use if statement it will be better ...

Comment: Put a `waitpid(pidA,NULL,0);` right before the second fork, or wherever you'd like it to wait.